# How to count matches in different querysets

Tags: python, django, templates, view, django-queryset

I want to count different querysets in my template after doing a search over all models but it seems that the different querysets are in a list of lists.

my view function:

```
class Search(ListView):

template_name='artdb/searchResult.html'

def get_queryset(self): # override get_queryset() has to have that name...

    q=self.request.GET.get('seastr')
    models=[Person,Activity,Member,Comment]
    fields=[l._meta.fields for l in models]
    res=[]

    for i,j in enumerate(models):
        sq=[Q(**{x.name + "__icontains" : q}) for x in fields[i] if not isinstance(x,ForeignKey)]
        res+=[j.objects.filter(k) or None for k in sq]

    res=[k for k in res if k]

    if q:
        return res
    else:
        return Person.objects.none()  # SELECT ... WHERE headline ILIKE '%Lennon%';

def get_context_data(self,*args,**kwargs):

    #q=self.request.GET.get('seastr')
    context=super().get_context_data(*args,**kwargs)     
    context['member']=Member.objects.all()
    return context
```

context dict:

```
{'page_obj': None, 'view': <artdb.views.Search object at 0x7f415ec88080>, 'is_paginated': False, 'object_list': [<QuerySet [<Person: David Bolander>, <Person: adam something>]>, <QuerySet [<Comment: david bolander comment>]>], 'member': <QuerySet [<Member: 2019-11-21>, <Member: 2020-02-10>]>, 'paginator': None}
```

my template:

```
{% extends "artdb/index.html" %}

{% block sr1 %}
    <ul>
      <a class="btn btn-light btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" role="button" href="{% url 'artdb:search' %}">
        Persons: {{object_list.count}}
      </a>
      <a class="btn btn-light btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" role="button" href="{% url 'artdb:search' %}">
    Activities: {{activity.count}}
      </a>
      <a class="btn btn-light btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" role="button" href="{% url 'artdb:search' %}">
    Members: {{member.count}}
      </a>
      <a class="btn btn-light btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" role="button" href="{% url 'artdb:search' %}">
    Comments: {{comment.count}}
      </a>
      <br></br>
</ul>
{% endblock sr1 %
```

As can be seen in the template, I want to count the matches in the `<a>` tag but the querysets are stacked as lists of lists in the context dictionary. For example, member can be counted because it was added later and it is not in a list of lists. how do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I found a solution to this. I insert the object_list again in the context dict:

```
def get_context_data(self,*args,**kwargs):

        context=super().get_context_data(*args,**kwargs)

        c=context['object_list']
        cname=[l.model.__name__ for l in c]

        for l in zip(cname,c):
            context[l[0].lower()]=l[1]

        return context
```

it's not the most elegant solution and if anyone else has another solution, please share it.